# rsyslog - relaying only remotely received messages (edit: nxlog will be better)

Tags: rsyslog

I am looking at building a syslog relay in order to move from my clients'-enforced UDP stream to TCP. Specifically, I would like to move from

```
client --UDP_PORT_999--> server1
```

to

```
client --UDP_PORT_999--> server1 --TCP_PORT_514--> server2
```

I found in the rssylog documentation both [how to setup remote (client and server) syslog](http://rsyslog.com/receiving-messages-from-a-remote-system/) and how to correctly [configure failover](http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/FailoverSyslogServer) (in case where server2 is not available) but I do not know how to translate "*forward to server2 only messages coming from a remote client*" (or, alternatively, "*forward to server2 only messages coming on port UDP 999*"). In other words I would like to keep local syslog processing on server1 and simply proxy what comes in via UDP to outgoing messages via TCP.

I am not religiously attached to rsyslog so if there is a good way to set this up (including failover) on syslog-ng it would be perfect as well.

Thank you for any pointers!

WoJ

PS. I posted the question on the rsyslog forum just to realize afterwards that I will be probably better off posting my question here :)

**EDIT: [nxlog](http://nxlog-ce.sourceforge.net/) will be a better solution (see answer below & my comment)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can also recommend you [nxlog](http://nxlog.org) as its configuration allows you to more naturally define the flow what you specified above.

Config skeleton:

```
<Input udpin>
 Module im_udp
 ...
</Input>

<Output tcpout>
 Module om_tcp
 ...
</Output>

<Route forwarder>
 Path udpin => tcpout
</Route>
```

Comment: I happened to discover nxlog yesterday and it exactly fullfils my needs, and does it better than rsyslog. It uses buffering in a very natural way and, as you mentionned, has a natural and simple configuration. I am switching to it for general logging soon.

Answer (score 2):

I found a reasonable way to achieve this by adding the following config line to `/etc/rsyslog.conf` on server1:

```
:fromhost-ip, !isequal, "127.0.0.1" @@server2
```

(rsyslog documentation states that `$fromhost-ip`=127.0.01 for local messages)

The configuration works, as tested with the excellent [remote-syslog](http://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog).

Comment: rsyslog can read local log file by itself using the imfile input module. See http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imfile.html