# How to prevent rsyslog from relaying messages

Tags: rsyslog

How can I make `rsyslog` behave like the default of the old `syslog`, that it will *not* be relaying (not forward messages coming from remote hosts to another host)? I.e., that it will only forward locally generated messages?

Edit:

I still want both remote and local messages logged to the local harddisk, like this:

A* --> B --> C

- Computer B receives logs originating from computers A* and stores them on disk.
- Computer C receives logs originating from B and stores them on disk. C does not receive logs originating from A*.
- All computers store their own, local logs on disk as well.
- I am even considering to add forwarding of logs from C to B.

Comment: Have you tried blocking TCP/UDP 601 and TCP/UDP 514?

Comment: @AdrianK I want to receive, but not relay (see edit).

Comment: You might want to look at this post which asked for the opposite [rsyslog - relaying only remotely received messages (edit: nxlog will be better](http://serverfault.com/questions/345894/rsyslog-relaying-only-remotely-received-messages-edit-nxlog-will-be-better)).